# Read mail from office 365 from VS2013/ VS2015 via C#

Tags: email, office365

I'm new to office 365, Can anybody explain how to read office 365 mails by using Office 365 APIs in Visual Studio via c#. I need step by step of work flow and what the software required. If you have any related Links also available that also helpful for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read emails from exchange online (Office 365) through windows forms application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722482/read-emails-from-exchange-online-office-365-through-windows-forms-application)

Answer (score 0):

The mail API for Office 360 is defined on: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations

You can find several sources online to find how to develop an application that calls an API. This is a nice example: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client If you follow that tutorial it'll be a lot more clear how to do this.

For software I think Visual Studio would be sufficient.